# How to write lines of one file into individual files in their own directories?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, grep, printf

I have a script that I need to read each line of a file, and print those lines individually into their own subdirectory that is based on the linenumber.

I have a file called input.data that has one number I need to change and put the a copy of that file into directories like so:

input.data:

```
60 13 44.375 3 500 1.8
```

sizes.txt:

```
44.732
44.733
44.823
44.532
```

I need to take the third number of input.data, substitute it with line 1 of sizes.txt and put it in a directory called frame0001, then do the same with the remaining lines of the sizes.txt file so that it ends up with the format

```
frame0001/input.data
frame0002/input.data
frame0003/input.data
```

...

I've tried using combinations of awk, grep, and echo inside of a for loop, but I don't know how to have awk take NR to be the value of a variable outside of awk.

I have used:

```
mkdir $(printf "frame%04i" $(seq 1 475))
```

to make directories frame0001-frame0475

then I used:

```
i=1; for file in frame*; do cp "input.data" $(printf "frame%04i/a.out" "$i"); i=$((i+1)); done
```

to copy the input.data file into each directory as it is, but editing each file by hand will take a long while. I would like to automate this process to be able to read the sizes.txt file, and change the input.data file in each directory, or edit the input.data file first then place in each directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/env bash
cnt=0
while IFS= read -r size; do
    printf -v dir 'frame%04d' $(( ++cnt ))
    mkdir -p "$dir" &&
    awk -v size="$size" '{$3=size}1' input.data > "${dir}/input.data"
done < sizes.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is the most insightful way to combine everything in one loop. I didn't know you could use awk in such a way.

Comment: I was wondering if you were going to somehow pull a rabbit out of your hat and do it all in `awk`. But a read loop and `awk` replacement seems about as logical as anything else.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the `mkdir` means it can't all be done in awk. I mean you could call mkdir indirectly from awk but then you'd have a calling tree like `shell { awk { system { shell { mkdir }}}}` instead of just `shell { mkdir; awk }` so it'd clearly be the wrong approach. I **might** consider it, though, if there was a lot more text manipulation necessary to come up with the directory name but that's not the case here.

Comment: Good point. That is the "nut-and-bolts" of the thought process that escaped me at first glance.